# Check file existence in another location and then copy files based on condition in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

There is a folder where users place files at random times. These files are all read-only. We need to read files every hour and if there is a file in the last one hour we need to copy it(not delete or change) to another directory. The files are normally of pattern Bank_YYMMDD.csv where YYMMDD is variable ex: Bank_20200927.csv.

/outbound is where the files are placed and /daily is where the files need to be copied.
I have tried the below code and it works fine.

```
find /outbound -type f -mmin -60 -name "Bank*" | xargs -ILIST cp LIST /daily/
```

The problem part:
Once files are placed in /daily a separate business process checks and processes these files and after processing moves them to /processed.
There is an additional requirement to check the processed folder i.e. /processed and if the file we are trying to place already exists in the /processed folder then do not copy this file to /daily.

Ex: 3 files are placed or modified in the last hour in /outbound
Say the 3 files are Bank_20200927.csv, Bank_20200926.csv, and Bank_20200925.csv.
Out of these 3 files, the process ran earlier and already picked Bank_20200926.csv, and Bank_20200925.csv and placed them in /daily. Then the business process ran and now /processed folder already has the Bank_20200926.csv and Bank_20200925.csv.

So this time even though Bank_20200926.csv and Bank_20200925.csv were picked as they were modified and satisfies the modified in last one hour check the only file to be copied to the /daily folder will be Bank_20200927.csv.

I am stuck with the part to check if /processed has the files and if not only then place it in /daily.

Kindly help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use something like that :

```
for i in /outbound/*.csv;do [[ $(($(date +"%s")-$(stat -c %Y $i))) -lt 3600 && ! -e /processed/${i##*/} ]] && cp $i /daily/;done
```

Comment: I think we do not need a date check to implement. Since files placed on Monday can be from Friday. Or a day earlier if Friday was a holiday.

Comment: The date statement is only to verify the files are less than 60 mins old.

Comment: I just change the filepath, filename pattern and time to the below.

for i in /interfaces/sftp/output/"Bank*";do [[ $(($(date +"%s")-$(stat -c %Y $i))) -lt 900 && ! -e /interfaces/file/archive/${i##*/} ]] && cp $i /interfaces/file/in/;done

I saved it as a .sh script and tried to run it via the OS Command line. However, it does nothing. It does not give me any error but also it does nothing. I had a file /interfaces/sftp/output/Bank_20200928.csv but the /interfaces/file/in/ remains blank.

Comment: Update. The copy function works after I moved the asterix out of the "" i.e. /interfaces/sftp/output/"Bank"* instead of /interfaces/sftp/output/"Bank*"